# How do I ng-watch a variable from a ViewModel and update it in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a :

```
ng-click="like(photo.Id)"
```

...which fires a http post call to update data in the database.

The photo object comes from a ViewModel and can be accessed in the HTML by using ex {{photo.Likes}}. This.. gives me the number of likes and works like it should..

But.. I need to update the count in the html page when the ng-click="like...." function is clicked by the user.

So.. I am trying to do something like this :

```
<span ng-watch="{{photo.Likes}}"></span>
```

but clearly.. I don't understand well enough how this stuff works.

Here is the $http call which fills $scope.photo. Do i need to add some watch logic here too ?

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/ViewImage/GetPhotoById/' + $routeParams.id,
    accept: 'application/json'
})
        .success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            $scope.photo = result;
        });
```

Comment: Just increment $scope.photo.likes in the like method and just have {{photo.likes}}. No extra watch logic needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just putting expression in the double mustaches like `{{ photo.Likes }}` makes a binding which will update your html once the value is updated.

Create a method for `ng-click` that will change the value (I think you got this part already)

So overall it going to be something like below:

```
  <span ng-click='like(photo.photoId)'>like</span>

  <span>{{photo.Likes}}</span>
```

And in controller:

```
  ....controller(function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.photo = null

      $scope.like = function(photo) {
          photo.Likes++
      }         

      $http({
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/api/ViewImage/GetPhotoById/' + $routeParams.id,
          accept: 'application/json'
      })
      .success(function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          $scope.photo = result;
      });

  })
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :) Sometimes... the world is easier than it looks like :D

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
<span>{{photo.Likes}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-watch` as a directive, does not exist.

You need to create something within your controller, service, directive etc to use: `$scope.$watch`